# How can I retrieve the only email id from the entire Contacts?

Tags: android, email, android-contacts

I have a button in my `main.xml` file. When I click the button it will show  the list of email 
id's of the entire contact list. That means Retrieve the contact's email id if it has.I need
the email id not the contacts. Is there any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check out the code.

```
 Public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails(){
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                            new String[]{id}, null); 
            while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                //to get the contact names
                String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.e("Name :", name);
                String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                Log.e("Email", email);
                if(email!=null){
                    names.add(name);
                }
            } 
            cur1.close();
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: your code has some error I tried the entire code on the button click

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
package stack.examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class StackOverFlowGetContactsActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvItem;
    private Button btnAdd;
    String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
    ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);  
       btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
       itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
       lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
       btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               GetEmails();
           }
       });
    }

    private void GetEmails()
    {
        ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {       
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
            while (emails.moveToNext()) 
            {               
                emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                contactlist.add(emailAddress);
                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            emails.close();

        }
        cursor.close(); 
    }
}
```